# Applied base filter to timelion

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, timelion

So in timelion you can do something like this: `.es('user="bob"').divide(.es())`

I would like to apply a base filter, is there a way to do it without duplicating the filter like this:
`.es('user="bob" AND type="singer"').divide(.es(type="singer"))`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a non official feature in timelion of Variables that can help.
Please notice that this is not an official feature.
Also, I could not find a way to concat a variable and a string, so not sure it can help for the base filter idea...

More info here: 
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/applied-base-filter-to-timelion/168886/3